# Reactjs import dynamically js file with default export function

Tags: reactjs

I have a reactjs app
In MyApp component I use an import at top like this:

```
import { ProvideAuth } from "util/auth.js";
```

Internally this file util/auth.js I have this code (I import another js file at top like this):

```
import analytics from "./analytics";

export function ProvideAuth({ children }) {
  .....
}
```

How can I make this **import analytics from "./analytics"** dynamically depending on a cookie value?.
I made this code, but it doesn't work:

```
function loadLazyModule() {
  console.log("loadLazyModule");
  const _module = React.lazy(() =>
    import("./analytics.js")
  );
  return _module;
}

// Provider hook that creates auth object and handles state
export function ProvideAuth({ children }) {
  if (statisticsCookie == 'Y') {
    console.log("statisticsCookie", statisticsCookie);
    loadLazyModule();
  }
 .....
}
```

Finally my analytics.js has this code:

```
// Initialize analytics and plugins
// Documentation: https://getanalytics.io
const analytics = Analytics({
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
  plugins: [
    googleAnalyticsPlugin({
      trackingId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GA_TRACKING_ID,
    }),
  ],
});
....

export default analytics;
```

I need to this file import only if my cookie is enabled (has value 'Y'):

```
import analytics from "./analytics";
```

Help me please!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this.
you can also use, .than().catch() function after that.

```
async function load() {
let say = await import('./say.js');
say.hi(); // Hello!
say.bye(); // Bye!
say.default(); // Module loaded (export default)!
```

}

or via import module

```
 let modulePath = prompt("Which module to load?");
 import(modulePath)
 .then(obj => <module object>)
 .catch(err => <loading error,e.g. if no such module>)
```

it's described here
https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports